# How is password removed from a pdf file programmatically?

Tags: pdf

One of password protected PDF I encountered has trailer and encryption dictionary as follows:

```
Trailer Dictionary:  
trailer
<<  
    /Encrypt 64 0 R  
    /Info 65 0 R  
    /Root 63 0 R 
    /Size 66  
    /ID [xxxxxxxx]>>  

Encryption Dictionary:
64 0 obj 
    <<   
    /R 3   
    /P -3904  
    /O (xxxxxxxxxxxxx)  
    /Filter /Standard  
    /Length 128  
    /V 2  
    /U (/xxxxxxxxxxxxx) >>  
endobj
```

Comment: Is my question wrong ?

Comment: I assume the down-votes and close-calls occurred because you want to *remove password from a pdf file (**not using any software**)*. How do you expect to do that without any software?

Comment: I want it just by manipulating internal structure of pdf. Any software is also a code by which we remove password. I want internal working of that code i.e how that software is removing password, what it is actually doing internally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In comments the OP clarified that by *not using any software* he meant

> Any software is also a code by which we remove password. I want internal working of that code i.e how that software is removing password, what it is actually doing internally.

Thus, this question is not about *manually removing PDF password protection* but about *understanding how PDF password protection is removed programmatically.*

---

PDF passwords are applied by encryting *nearly* all strings and streams in the PDF and adding the information the OP already identified. Consequentially PDF passwords are removed by decrypting the formerly encrypted strings and streams in the PDF and removing the added information.

The details of this are explained in section *7.6 Encryption* in the PDF specification ISO 32000-1 and are too extensive for an answer on stack**overflow**. Fortunately Adobe has provided a free copy of that specification only missing the ISO logo and copyright notices [here](https://www.adobe.com/go/pdfreference/) in which one can study the section in question and more.

Comment: Thanks, my main question is that only "understanding how PDF password protection can be removed programmatically". Now i get my answer and i will try to remove password protection programmatically.